# multi threading scanf from thread while pther thread printf in c programming

Tags: c, multithreading

For my game project dots , i use multi threading for displaying time passed for the user but while user input
The cursor overlap the user input before he finish his input
So i want to fix a thread to the console with out affecting user input

Comment: Without *synchronization* between the threads you can not stop the "overlap". I suggest you rethink your design so you have all output *and* input in a single thread. Otherwise console input/output will be very hard to handle.

Comment: If i want even the input to be entered on other console is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something like this, which is in my notes taken from Linux System Programming book:

`Manual File Locking`

The function flockfile() waits until stream is no longer locked, bumps the lock count,
and then acquires the lock, becoming the owning thread of the stream, and returns:

`#include <stdio.h>
void flockfile (FILE *stream);`

The function funlockfile() decrements the lock count associated with stream:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void funlockfile (FILE *stream)

flockfile (stream);

fputs ("List of treasure:\n", stream);
fputs (" (1) 500 gold coins\n", stream);
fputs (" (2) Wonderfully ornate dishware\n", stream);

funlockfile (stream);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am using  windows not linux .ide codeblocks how can i avoid multithreaing printing and scanfing overlaping each other

Comment: Usually windows steals or already stole fron xUNIX many functions, look for similar function equivalent to flockfile() then.